# Adding audio to video being created with image2pipe option

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I am creating a video in mp4 format from a sequence of images and an MP3 audio file.
For performance reasons I switched from **image2** option to **image2pipe** option and now video is creating OK but without an audio,

Is it possible at all to add an audio while pipe processing images or it should be done afterwards a separate step?

my FFMPEG command:

```
$command = $ffmpegpath ." -f image2pipe -pix_fmt rgb24 -r 20 -c:v png -i - ".
    "-i " .$mp3path ." "
    "-r 20 -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p ".
    "-y " .$outputpath;
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Please show the *actual* command you used (not with variables etc.), and the full, uncut ffmpeg console output. Make sure to try this with a recent version, either a static build (http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) or a self-compiled binary.

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm trying to something similar. (Trying to write generated audio/video to disk in real time via Python...)

Comment: Did it  as a separate step afterward. No solution, sorry.